# Determining whether a set is open and bounded

Tags: general-topology

I know that given $a < b$ and $g(x) \le h(x)$

$\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^n |\ a \le x \le b, \ g(x) \le y \le h(x) \}$

is a closed constrained/bounded/limited (not sure what the terminology is in english :) ) set.

I also know that one can show this by visually drawing the constraints and demonstrate that they are limited, i.e. can be surrounded by a finite circle or something.

But.... is there a way to show this algebraically in some way? If I only had one constraint, I would show that both $x$ and $y$ are limited and cannot get too large. Ex: $|x| + |y| \le 3$ is limited as either variable has the low points -3 and high points 3

But what to do when the domain is given as above?

For example (completely random example):

$\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^n |\ 0 \le x \le 4, \ x-2 \le y \le x \}$

I'm fairly sure I could get away with simply saying "I know that sets of these type are limited, as mentioned in the book", but I'd like to be more concrete and perhaps show it algebraically, if possible?

Comment: I am pretty sure the word you are looking for is “bounded”. A variable is typically called constrained if it is required to take values in some subset, for example given by an equation $f(x)=0$, but you rarely (if ever) call a set constrained.

Comment: If $g$ and $h$ are continuous on $[a,b]$, then they are bounded. You can easily get a bound for your set from that.

Answer (score 1):

In order to show that a set $S$ is bounded in $\mathbb{R}^n$, you must show that it is a subset of a "ball" of some size. A ball $B(a,x)$, where $a\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $x$ is a real number is defined as the set of points that are distance less than $x$ away from $a$. $B(0,x)=\{a\in \mathbb{R^n} : d(0,a)<x\}$

In your example, you are working in $R^2$ and can show by the distance formula that your set is bounded by the ball $B(0,4.5)$.

Comment: How did you figure it out that B(0,4.5) would bound it?

Answer (score 0):

If $g$ and $h$ are continuous on $[a,b]$, then they are uniformly continuous, hence obtains minimum and maximum. Hence you can get a lower bound and upper bound for $y$.

If they are not continuous on $[a,b]$, the set is not necessary bounded. For example, $a=0,b=1, g(x)=0, h(0)=0 \quad\text{and}\quad h(x)=\frac{1}{x}, x\in (0,1].$